# Google Homegraph API: can't send status:"ERROR" in reportState

Tags: google-api, google-home, google-smart-home

When I send this JSON with reportState() to the Google Homegraph API

```
{
  "requestId":"15cdee88-e804-4352-a2f9-4eace7eb119d",
  "agentUserId":"18807",
  "payload":{
    "devices":{
       "states":{"9196":{"status":"ERROR","errorCode":"deviceStuck"}}
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error

```
reporting device state to homegraph: {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

The target device is a mower with these traits

```
traits: [
      "action.devices.traits.StartStop",
      "action.devices.traits.Dock",
    ],
```

Is it possible to set an error for a device in the homegraph API?
And if yes how should the JSON look?

edit: using those package version if that's relevant

```
  "@googleapis/homegraph": "^2.0.0",
    "actions-on-google": "^2.13.0",
```

Comment: If you look at the [ReportStateAndNotificationDevice](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rest/v1/devices/reportStateAndNotification#reportstateandnotificationdevice) reference material, it suggests that errors cannot be reported.

Answer (score 0):

You can return errors or exceptions for a device within `EXECUTE` and `QUERY` responses. Examples of this are available on the [errors reference guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/errors-exceptions). You can also see a more detailed example of this in the [Smart Home traits codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-traits/#5).